# Highchart, Can we export multi-page PDF file or do we have to use another PDF?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can we export multi-page PDF file or do we have to use another PDF? Any advice as I can't figure out how to do a multi-page PDF?
[`LINK DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/teeraphongsing/5940ku6r/7/)
 I would like to have a separate page between the graph and the data table so that all data can be displayed fully in both the graph and the data table. like this [image]
Or if not, then set the page to display both graph and data table when pressing export.

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support this feature. Maybe you should try to implement a custom HTML table and use some other tools for exporting.

Comment: instead of having the data table at the bottom of the chart Can it be switched to have the data table on the side of the chart?

Comment: Yes, it can, take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wahuy03d more info you can find here: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41949