# Highchart, Can we keep the data table on the side of the chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem where the chart has so much data that a normal data table can't see all the data on one page, and highchart can't export 2 sheets of data. So I wanted to know if we could put the data table on the side of the chart. like this[image: Picture]
This demo [`Link Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/)

Comment: Answer to this question was added in the comment section under related topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71907998/highchart-can-we-export-multi-page-pdf-file-or-do-we-have-to-use-another-pdf

Comment: Can it export a PDF with a grid of data tables? If we make a data table beside the chart